# Symfony 4+ form validation done in a controller action?

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4

I understand how constraints are applied in Form types, etc.

But in the case of implementing a password reset, I need to check for the existence of an email and error if it does not exist.

How might one achieve that in Symfony 4+?

This doesn't seem to solve my issue:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html

Comment: It would probably help to show the controller code. I don't quite follow the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom constraints for your form input fields. 
See : https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

For custom constraint you need to specify constraint and validator classes like this:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class NonExistingEmail extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Email does not exist';
}
```

```
class NonExistingEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof NonExistingEmail) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, NonExistingEmail::class);
        }

        // custom constraints should ignore null and empty values to allow
        // other constraints (NotBlank, NotNull, etc.) take care of that
        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(["email" => $value])

        if (!$user) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone down voted your answer and didn't explain why...I voted your answer up, but I have not yet tried it, so I cannot confirm whether it solves my problem. I will hopefully sometime this week and if it works, I'll accept your answer. Thank you for your time :)